# maintenance page for cap deploy does not work ( it is not shown )

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, nginx, capistrano, setup-deployment

**Maintenance page for cap deployment does not work. Ive tried to debug but do not see my mistake anyone see what I miss here why its not working? Thx**

When I do cap:web:disabled Its not showing the maintenance page but rather just the app!

*In deploy.rb I have:*

```
  namespace :deploy do
  namespace :web do
     task :disable, :roles => :web do
       require 'erb'
       on_rollback { run "rm #{shared_path}/system/maintenance.html" }

       reason = ENV['REASON']
       deadline = ENV['UNTIL']
       template = File.read('app/views/layouts/maintenance.html.erb')
       page = ERB.new(template).result(binding)

       put page, "#{shared_path}/system/maintenance.html", :mode => 0644
     end
   end
```

*My Nginx Config for the app:*

```
  upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/srv/books/shared/tmp/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 deferred;
  server_name books.ltd;

  root /srv/books/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
        return 503;
  }

  error_page 503 @maintenance;
  location @maintenance {
      rewrite  ^(.*)$  /system/maintenance.html last;
      break;
  }

  #error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only help with Nginx, but here's how I would do it:

```
  root /srv/books/public;

  location / {
      try_files /system/maintenance.html $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  }

  location @unicorn {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }
```

The only functional difference between the two is that the user will get a 200 instead of 503, but I assume you are using that code just to leverage the error handling to get to your rewrite anyway.

Incidentally, the reason your solution doesn't work is because you rewrite to /system/maintenance.html, but you have no location that will serve that file.  So Nginx searches again for the new location, encounters your try_files, and passes the request along to @unicorn, since there's no other matching location.  If you added

```
location = /system/maintenance.html { }
```

Then likely your solution would work, but I'd still suggest that mine is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Thx Cliff for the clear description, it makes all sense to me - so I tried it but still the problem persist, I have restart app + nginx it seems that cap:deploy:web:disable and server restarts still doesn't show me the maintenance page. It is there though

Comment: If you directly request /system/maintenance.html (using curl or your browser), what do you get in Nginx logs?

Comment: Im looking at that at this moment yes. Since that path is non existent. The problem is its /srv/books/current/.. app here and /srv/books/shared/system/maintance so I guess thats where it goes wrong.

Comment: I could add a maintenance.html to the /public but then you could do site.com/maintenance.html not nice also not because of indexing search engines, perhaps simlinking the system folder in is the way to go. I think your nginx config is nice very short I replaced mine!

Comment: You could also try to use alias before try_files

Comment: or... change your root to /srv/books, then use try_files /shared/system/maintenance.html /public/$uri/index.hml /public/$uri @unicorn  ... sorry for the poor formatting, it appears I can't use line breaks in a comment =(

Comment: last comment: I think worrying about indexing search engines is misplaced.  The maintenance.html file is only there while site is undergoing maintenance, so if it's not undergoing maintenance, everything still gets sent to @unicorn.

Comment: Ok I think its more an issue with my placement and linking of the file and the answer is almost certain correct so I grand it the winning one. Im going to solve it with a symlink. thx

Answer (score 1):

I found this page after quite some research. It might be of help to people with similar problems. http://blog.oncompare.com/2011/01/25/setting-up-a-maintenance-page-with-passenger-nginx-and-rails/

Comment: thx for posting, yours is tailored towards passenger. I already had the try_files solution. Could be helpfull for passenger people

Answer (score 0):

You can use below example as is just replacing some paths if you are working with nginx with unicorn -

```
upstream unicorn {
      server unix:/tmp/unicorn.rrorder.sock fail_timeout=0;
    }

server {
  listen             80;
  server_name       example.com;

  root /home/deployer/apps/test/current/public;

    location ~* ^/assets/ {
        root /home/deployer/apps/test/current/public;
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header Last-Modified "";
        add_header ETag "";
        break;
    }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_pass        http://unicorn;
  }
  error_page 503 @503;
    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
     return 503;
    }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location @503 {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
    }
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 30;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout    300;
    proxy_read_timeout    300;
}
```

This is my workable nginx configuration, you have to just add below code that will work.

```
  error_page 503 @503;
    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
     return 503;
    }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location @503 {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
    }
```

then add below code in your deploy.rb or production.rb capistrano file

```
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :web do
    desc "Enable maintenance mode for apache"
    task :disable, :roles => :web do
      on_rollback { run "rm -f #{shared_path}/system/maintenance.html" }
      page = File.read('public/maintenance.html')
      put page, "#{shared_path}/system/maintenance.html", :mode => 0644
    end

    desc "Disable maintenance mode for apache"
    task :enable, :roles => :web do
      run "rm -f #{shared_path}/system/maintenance.html"
    end
  end 
end
```

Add maintenance.html file in the public folder with some below content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>The page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: #fff; color: #666; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
    div.dialog {
      width: 48em;
      padding: 0 4em;
      margin: 4em auto 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-right-color: #999;
      border-bottom-color: #999;
    }
    h1 { font-size: 100%; color: #f00; line-height: 1.5em; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dialog">
    <h1>Maintenance Mode</h1>
    <p>"We are currently carrying out essential scheduled maintenance.
        Normal service will resume shortly.  Apologies for any inconvenience." </p>

    <p>Sorry for the inconvenience!</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

See below are the rake tasks will be available to use -

```
cap deploy:web:enable
cap deploy:web:disable

cap production deploy:web:enable
cap production deploy:web:disable

cap staging deploy:web:enable
cap staging deploy:web:disable
```

This will definitely work like charm!

Cheers!